# How to sort arrival and departure times in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, time

I have the following lists denoting, arrival and departure times of trains.

```
arr  = ['9:00',  '9:40', '9:50',  '11:00', '15:00', '18:00']
dep  = ['9:10', '12:00', '11:20', '11:30', '19:00', '20:00']
```

I want to merge and sort them. I did the following.

```
final = sorted(arr+dep)
```

Output:

```
['11:00', '11:20', '11:30', '12:00', '15:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '9:00', '9:10', '9:40', '9:50']
```

**Expected Output:**  (Actual sort of the timestamps)

```
['9:00', '9:10', '9:40', '9:50','11:00', '11:20', '11:30', '12:00', '15:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00']
```

How do I achieve the expected output?

Comment: Notice they are strings.

Comment: It is because they are string as TheGreat told

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strings sort lexicographically.  `'9:00'` will come after `'11:00'` because, for strings, `'9'` is greater than `'1'`.

To solve this problem, you'll probably want to split on `':'` and create integers from the values:

```
def sort_key(time):
    hour, minute = time.split(':')
    return int(hour), int(minute)

arr  = ['9:00',  '9:40', '9:50',  '11:00', '15:00', '18:00']
dep  = ['9:10', '12:00', '11:20', '11:30', '19:00', '20:00']
sorted(arr + dep, key=sort_key)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this one

```
>>> import datetime
>>> arr  = ['9:00',  '9:40', '9:50',  '11:00', '15:00', '18:00']
>>> dep  = ['9:10', '12:00', '11:20', '11:30', '19:00', '20:00']
>>> sorted(dep+arr, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M'))
['9:00', '9:10', '9:40', '9:50', '11:00', '11:20', '11:30', '12:00', '15:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00']
```